# Не видит переменную PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php  $resultdi = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM temp_diagnoz WHERE id = $id AND fio = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$fio)."' " ) 
    or die(mysqli_error($con));         
     ?> 

   <?php    while($rowd = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultdi )) { 
   $jaloby =  $rowd["jaloby"]; 
   $diagnoz =  $rowd["diagnoz"]; 
   $obekt =  $rowd["obekt"]; 
    }  ?>
```

Внизу например пишу

```
<?php echo $jaloby ;?>
```

Выдает ошибку Notice Undefined variable: jaloby in ... хотя переменная же есть в чем может быть проблема ? Где и что делаю не так

Comment: А переменной может не быть, так как у вас запрос вернул пустой результат.

Comment: Об этом тоже подумал и проверил в базе есть запись отвечающий критериям запроса (

Comment: Вы лучше внутри цикла while() сделайте вывод `var_dump($rowd);` и убедитесь есть данные или нет.

Comment: Странно , но внутри цикла не выводит ничего ... а за циклом просто NULL

Comment: Текст запроса выведите себе на экран и выполните его в phpMyAdmin для проверки поведения.

Comment: И в очередной раз Вы мне помогли Visman ) даже не знаю как отблагодарить ) оказывается в запросе была ошибка там нету поля id а есть card_id ) Большое Вам спасибо